# Is there a way to nest an Excel spreadsheet within another Excel spreadsheet?

Tags: windows, excel, spreadsheet

I am not entirely sure if this is the place to ask this, but this is the only think I could think of. I want to know if I could have a spreadsheet, say 10 cells wide. I would like the first 5 cells to be static, and the second 5 to be A/B based on, I guess a drop down? Not sure if this is possible, thanks for the input.

Comment: Was the answer given, helpful?

Answer (score 1):

Both are possible.

In regards to the static question, you want to look at Excel's ability to Split the worksheet and then Freeze sections. With Excel 2007 you can find this within the View ribbon and Window group. (I am not sure of the exact menu terminology.)

For a cell to act as a Dropdown, you want to look at Data Validation. This option (with Excel 2007) is found under the Data ribbon within the Data Tools section. This allows you to set a given cell to dates, times, whole numbers, and lists. With the list you set the source to a range elsewhere in the workbook and the cell will render as a dropdown.

Hope this helps.